# wordpress php add value to database

Tags: php, mysql, database, wordpress

I'm very new to the idea of adding values to a database, so would like some advise on whether this is possible and how I would do it.

I have a code that counts the lines of code written in a project, the code has to be in the folder that it is counting the lines of code from however I want to display this number on my site elsewhere. My site is a wordpress one, so i thought of sending this number to the database and calling on it in a template file elsewhere.

Is there a way to send this number to my database and have it keep up to date in real-time so that I can call it from other places in my site?

My LOC script can be seen running here:
http://www.skizzar.com/wp-content/loc.php

and the number is displayed using the command:

```
$folder -> count_lines()
```

**update**

I've added the following code to my loc.php

```
$num_of_lines = $folder -> count_lines();
add_option('line_count', $num_of_lines);
```

And called it in my theme files using

```
echo get_option('line_count', '0');
```

So far this just returns 0 as the value and causes a fatal error on loc.php "call to undefined function..."

**Second update**

Got the code to work by adding

```
require_once('wp-config.php');
```

To the top of my code, the issue now is that it doesn't update in real time - is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are saving the value to the database with wordpress as well, use [add_option](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_option) and [get_option](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_option). Something like this:

```
add_option('line_count', $num_of_lines);
```

And in your template, display it with:

```
echo get_option('line_count', '0');
```

Comment: this just returns 0 - does that mean it's not adding to the database?

Comment: The example has 0 as a default.  It is likely not added to the database in that case.  Use add_option first within a Wordpress file.  Perhaps functions.php to initially set the value.

Comment: I also get a fatal error on loc.php - does that give any clues as to whats going on there?

Comment: Fatal error for which function: get or add?  My guess is that you're trying to set it outside of Wordpress, but retrieve it within wordpress.  Correct?

Comment: for add, yes I think that is my issue that I am trying to set it outside of wordpress - is there a way around this?

Comment: See mysql/php example here: http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_insert.asp  Do `INSERT IGNORE INTO` instead of `INSERT INTO` and the table name is likely (but not absolutely) `wp_options`.  Value should be same as the get_option value.  Good luck.

Comment: Also, to update the value later, use `UPDATE wp_options SET line_count = whatever-the-new-value-is`.